# Android - extends generic class

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance

I have 2 classes (A & B) inherited from a base abstract class (C). This parent class (C) implements some common functions for both of its children classes (A & B) and must be inherited from different classes. So, I decided to make it `generic` one. But I do not know it is possible or not and how to do it. Take a look at my code below:

**Parent class:**

```
//THIS PARENT CLASS MUST BE GENERIC TO EXTEND DIFFERENT CLASSES 
//SUCH AS Preference and LinearLayout
abstract class C<T> {

public C(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public C(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
}

public C(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

int commonFunc1(WebView view, int mode){
    //implementation
}

//lots of common functions

}
```

Preference and LinearLayout have the same constructors.

**A & B classes:**

```
//Class A must be inherited from the base class C that is inherited from LinearLayout
public class A extends C<LinearLayout>{

public A(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
}

public A(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

void exec(){
  commonFunc1(myWebView, 1);
}

}

//Class B must be inherited from the base class C that is inherited from Preference
public class B extends C<Preference>{

public B(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public B(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);      
}

public B(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

void exec(){
  commonFunc1(myWebView, 2);
}

}
```

So, my goal is to get class A inherited from `LinearLayout` with functionality of class C. And class B that inherited from `Preference` with the same functionality of class C.

I know about `interfaces` that can have `default` implementation, but it requires `Java 1.8 and above` that is not appropriate for me.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Your wording is really unclear. You don't inherit from different classes. When extending a generic class you can specify the generic type parameter, or not. That doesn't mean you inherit anything from that type parameter class.

Comment: @GhostCat, Is it possible to specify the ancestor class for class C from classes A & B, respectively

Comment: No, it is not. C extends Object. End of story. It seems you should study generics a bit more intensiv.

Comment: @GhostCat, that's why I asked this question. In my case I need to duplicate the code for both of classes A & B? Or there is a better solution?

Comment: i wonder what "common functions" you could have for completely unrelated classes like `LinearLayout` and `Preference`

Comment: @pskink, they are widgets that use `WebView` to show the content. So, they have some common functions

Comment: no, `android.preference.Preference` has little to do with any widget, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink, they both implement a banner. `Preference` is designed for using in `PreferenceScreen`. Actually, this is not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly its possible to achieve. A class cannot extend Generic type `T` only. Instead of trying to implement inheritance with some generic types, you can use composition.

You can do something like:

```
class A extends LinearLayout {

    ...

    ...
    // If C is expensive to create:
    private final C cObj;
    public A(final C cobj){
        this.cObj = cObj;
    }

    //If C needs to be created based on A then you can pass all the parameters needed for C as parameter for A's contructor

    void exec(){
        c.commonFunc1(myWebView, 2);
    }
}

class B extends Preference {

    ...
    private C c;
    ...
    //Use common functions of class C where-ever needed.

}
```

If its a required for making `class C` as abstract so that some specific inputs can be changed, then you still make `class C` as `abstract` and during initialization simply initialize it as anonymous class.

Comment: It's very inconvenient, due to the fact that I have to pass many variables to the functions of class C

Comment: @Nolesh You can still pass those parameter to constructor of A & B so that C can be initialized. Which anyways you need to do for constructing C. You can also initialize C first and pass object of C to A & B